# The limit of $(n!)^{1/n}/n$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

(Proof necessary)

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$

I don't have an answer yet, but I know it exists, and is less than $1$.

Edit. Winther's answer is the most correct I don't understand how he is jumping from (log(n!) - nlog( n )) to it equal to the Sum from k=1 to n of log(k/n). Don't presume, it's wrong, I need to go, and I'll keep looking at it when I get back

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this your limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$?

Comment: Hint: If the limit exists, let's say its $L$, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}=L^n$$

Comment: Stirling's formula will help you

Comment: [See this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791400/how-can-one-prove-lim-frac1n-frac-1-n-0/) for something very similar. It can be done without Strilings formula.

Comment: @Oria: The value of a limit (if it exists) cannot depend on the limiting variable. So "$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n} = L^n$" is definitely incorrect.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171904/limit-of-a-sequence-involving-root-of-a-factorial-lim-n-to-infty-fracn or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201906/showing-that-frac-sqrtnnn-rightarrow-frac1e or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn or some of other questions about this limit (There is plenty of them on this site.)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201906/showing-that-frac-sqrtnnn-rightarrow-frac1e Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn is even more suitable candidate for duplicate. (In the formulation of the question I have chosen the OP also asks about his attempted proof. But the answers also show other proofs, not only the one which the OP has suggested.)

Answer (score 15):

Put $$a_n = \frac{n!^{1/n}}{n}$$

then $$\log a_n = \frac{1}{n}\left(\log n! - n\log n\right)= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

where we have used $\log n! = \log 1 + \log 2 + \ldots + \log n$. The sum above is a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for the integral $\int_0^1\log x dx$ so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log a_n = \int_0^1\log x dx = [x\log x - x]_0^1 = -1$$

and it follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Hey winther I don't understand how you're jumping from (log(n!) - nlog( n )) to it equal to the Sum from k=1 to n of log(k/n).

Comment: @CalvinHammond $$\log n! - n \log n = \log 1 + \log 2 + \cdots + \log n - (\log n + \log n + \cdots + \log n),$$ where the number of terms in the parentheses is $n$.  So $$\log n! - n \log n = \log \frac{1}{n} + \log \frac{2}{n} + \cdots + \log \frac{n}{n}$$ using the identity $\log x - \log y = \log \frac{x}{y}$.  The rest follows.

Comment: Yes that is. Thanks for explaining it @heropup

Comment: Could you explain the remain sum more please.

Comment: Also what is the symbol at the beginning of 1+ log 2+ ...+ log n it keeps getting cut off

Comment: @CalvinHammond The sum comes about from using the log-rules $\log ab = \log a + \log b$ and $\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a - \log b$. Using this we have that $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n\log k$. And if I substract $n\cdot \log n = \log n + \log n + \ldots + \log n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log n$ from this we get $\log n! - n\log n = \sum_{k=1}^n (\log k - \log n) = \sum_{k=1}^n\log \frac{k}{n}$.

Comment: I know how you did that part, and that was right
its just your jump from 1/n* ∑ from k=1 to n of log(k/n) 
to the Reimann sum that has nothing to do with n in anything you said in that paragraph

Comment: @CalvinHammond The integral of a function $f(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ can be approximated as $\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\Delta x$ where $\Delta x = 1/n$ and $x_k = k/n$ (this is called a Riemann sum). If we now take $f(x)=\log x$ we get $(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k/n)$ which is what we have here. For large $n$ the approximation is better and better and if we take the limit $n\to\infty$ the sum converges to the integral, in symbols: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum \log(k/n) = \int_0^1\log x dx$.

Comment: Notice that you have to be a little careful in applying this technique to improper integrals: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449103/calculating-an-improper-integral-as-a-limit-of-a-sum

Comment: @user84413 Yes, I agree one have to be a bit careful when we have a singularity. In this case since the function is monotone the proof that it works is pretty simple: the difference between the integral and the upper/lower sums goes as $\frac{1}{n}\log(1/n)$ and since $\lim_{x\to 0} x\log x = 0$ we get convergence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and you're right that in this case the argument is fine since the function is monotonic.

Answer (score 8):

Let $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$.

Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}=\frac{1}{e}$,

so $\;\;\;\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$  $\hspace{.2 in}$ (since $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rightarrow L\implies(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow L)$.

Comment: This is a great proof, but you would need to prove that the two forms of the limit are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks; you are right that I am using the result that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=L$.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple elementary proof I found, but first of all, some lemmas:

- This one could easily be proven by induction: $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right) = n+1$
- You can try to prove this inequality yourself since it's not difficult: $\displaystyle \left (1+\frac{1}{k} \right )^k\leq e \leq \left (1+\frac{1}{k}  \right)^{k+1}\\$
- This inequality is the one I'm going to use though because it gives a much tighter bound on our sequence and that's just more fun, though you could use the second inequality without change in proof. I could give you the proof if needed:$\displaystyle \left (1+\frac{1}{k} \right )^k\leq e \leq \left (1+\frac{1}{k}  \right)^{k+1/2}\\$

Ok, so here is the proof:

> - We first write $n^n/n!$ in a better way: $\displaystyle \frac{n^n}{n!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^n \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{i}  \left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^{-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^n\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{-(n-i)}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{i}$
> - Now, we use our inequalities to bound our sequence. First, an upper bound: $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{i} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}e^{1}=e^{n-1}$
> - Then, a lower bound: $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{i} \geq \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left (e^{1} \cdot  \left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)^{-1/2} \right )=\frac{e^{n-1}}{\sqrt[2]{n}}$
> - Now, since $\frac{n!^{1/n}}{n}=(\frac{n^n}{n!})^{-1/n}$, we get: $\displaystyle e^{\frac{1}{n}-1}  \leq \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n} \leq e^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \cdot \sqrt[2n]{n}$
> - Finally, by the squeeze theorem, we get $\displaystyle e^{0-1}  \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n} \leq e^{0-1} \cdot 1$
> - Hence,  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}=e^{-1}$

I know there are simpler proofs, but this one is elementary and I feel like it gives you the direct intuition as to why it's true.

Answer (score 5):

**Stirling's Approximation** 
$$ n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$
Which means that $n!$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. If your familiar with asymptotic formulas, then you'd also know that this implies that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n} =1 $$
Now, using the algebraic laws of limits, we have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n!=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n $$
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right) $$
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{2n}}\left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right) $$
So now
$$ e=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\ln(2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{2n}}}\right]\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right] =\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{\ln(2\pi n)}{2n}}\right]\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right] $$
$$ =\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{\frac{d}{dn}\ln(2\pi n)}{\frac{d}{dn}2n}}\right]\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right] =\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\frac{1}{2n}}\right]\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right] $$
$$ =e^0\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right]=1\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}} $$
Thus
$$ e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}} $$
And now we can easily see that
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)}=\frac{1}{e} $$
Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Take the natural logarithm of $\dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$ and obtain
$$
\frac{\log 1+\log 2+\cdots+\log n}{n}-\log n=\frac{\log (1/n)+\log(2/n)+\cdots+\log(n/n)}{n}
\\=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
\to \int_0^1 \log x\,dx=-1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint (Sterling): $$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Comment: Yes that is my limit.  I'm using this to help a friend but I don't know much about to how to solve this myself. So I'm asking for a full answer.